# ExtJS 4 CellEditing plugin and Apply button

Tags: extjs4

I have a grid with CellEditing plugin.

```
Ext.define('SCR.view.UserDevice', {

    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
    id:'userDevice',
    alias:'widget.userdevice',
    title:"Devices",
    store:'UserDevices',
    sortableColumns:false,
    enableColumnHide:false,
    columns:[
        {
            header:'Device',
            width:200,
            dataIndex:'type'
        },
        {
            header:'Nickname',
            dataIndex:'name',
            width:300,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {
            header:'Registration Date',
            dataIndex:'registrationDate'
        }
    ],

    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],

    initComponent:function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

the editor is displayed after the click on the "Name" cell. Is it possible to add the Apply button after the input field?

Comment: The button wich will send ajax request to the server, for updating the Name field

Comment: Update will be send automatically after you leave the cell or press enter I believe.

Comment: I know that, but I need the button after input field, like in the RowEditing plugin